# setOnClickListener changes every seventh view in recyclerview

Tags: android-recyclerview

when i click an item in Recyclerview every seventh item gets the effect.

> onBindViewHolder:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.channelName.setText(list.get(position).getChannnelName());
        holder.linearLayoutChannelName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#93bcff"));
            }
        });
    }
    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        LinearLayout linearLayoutChannelName;
        TextView channelName;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            channelName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_channel_name);
            linearLayoutChannelName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.ll_channelname);
        }
    }
```

when i click an item every seventh item changes its backgroung color,and it repeats every seventh item in the list,  and even when scrolling across the list the background color dissapears.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/oq2sb.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOzQg.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use onClickListener in onBindViewHolder instead set it in onCreateViewHolder and create a member variable to set the selected item. You can do it like this.

```
int mSelectedItemPosition = -1;
```

// in your createViewHolder method

```
holder.linearLayoutChannelName.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                int position = holder.getAdapterPosition();
                if (position != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
                  mSelectedItemPosition = position;
                  notifyItemRangeChanged(0, yourList.size());
                }
            }
        });
```

And in your bind view holder check selected item position and set the background color

```
if(mSelectedItemPosition == position){
  view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#yourColor"))
}else{
  view.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("originalColor"));
}
```

Comment: no it didnt worked.
onBindviewholder i did this
holder.linearLayoutChannelName.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#93bcff"));

Comment: is your view bg color not changing after clicking or what?

Comment: its changing but its also changing every seventh view

Comment: :) i worked thank u very much. if its not a problem, can u explain to me i can't setonclicklistner in binder view ?

Comment: or you can give me any source where its explained in detail. :) 
thanks for the help.

Comment: Check this link (https://academy.realm.io/posts/360andev-yigit-boyar-pro-recyclerview-android-ui-java/) why not to use clickListeners in onBindViewHolder and can you please accept and up vote answer